# turn based movement on a tile grid, isolated tile(s)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

This is written in as3 and FlashPunk.

My problem? I have a tank that can move 4 tiles in the 4 directions; north,south,east and west.

Image can be found at http://www.aroderick.com/isolatedTiles.jpg

I've started with a square grid (Lt gray on the image) and used an array to mark out a diamond pattern (in red on the image) from the square grid, which are all the possible movement choices given the tank can only move 4 spaces in the 4 directions.
The tiles with numbers on the image are the actual tiles you see in the game, the numbers are the "col-row" numbers.

Where is gets a little more complex is that I've also removed tiles from the diamond where there are obstacles (water,trees,mountains) which in turn increases the movement cost to get to tiles beyond the obstacle(s).

I should mention at this point this is based on the A* algorithm and uses A* for movement but these are the movement choices that need to be established before a destination tile is chosen.

My problem is isolated tiles that are beyond the move ability of the tank and are isolated on their own from the main movement area where tiles are joined and make a complete path for A* and the tank can be moved from one tile to the next.

Is there a simple, elegant way to deal(get rid of) with these rogue tiles?

I've tried a system of rules i.e.;

```
    //same row going east           
    if(ob.row == co.row && ob.row == startNode.row && ob.col < co.col && ob.col > startNode.col && ob.c  <  co.c ) 
    {
        extraCost = co.c;
        reason = 1;
        break;
    }
    //same row going west
    else if(ob.row == co.row && ob.row == startNode.row && ob.col > co.col && ob.col < startNode.col && ob.c  <  co.c ) 
    {
        extraCost = co.c;
        reason = 2;
        break;
    }
```

Where "c" a a property representing the tile movement "cost" as the crow flies. 
But these seem to create as many problems as they solve.

```
    //reusable tile grid
    public static function makeTileGrid(entityLoc:Point,moveGrid:Array,travelMax:int,tsize:int = 64):Array
    {
        //node list
        var nodeLst:Array = [];
        //counter
        var tileCount:int = 0;
        //for tile naming
        var co_ordX:String = "";
        var co_ordY:String = "";
        if(moveNode == null) var moveNode:Object;
        //subtract the tile range from the current location
        //tile range times two because you can go forewards 
        //or backwards tRange spaces
        for (var col:int = travelMax * 2; col >=0;col--)
        {
            //placeX is an x value so you must multiply both row and tRange by the tile width
            var placeX:Number = entityLoc.x - (travelMax*64 - col*64);
            //trace(placeX);
            for(var row:int = travelMax * 2; row >=0;row--)
            {
                var placeY:Number = entityLoc.y - (travelMax*64 - row*64);

                //trace(moveGrid[col]);

                //use tile grid map array
                if(moveGrid[tileCount] == 1)
                {
                    //use coordinates for the name value e.g. 
                    co_ordX = col.toString();
                    co_ordY = row.toString();
                    moveNode = {col:col,row:row,obst:false,node:co_ordX+"-"+co_ordY,nX:placeX,nY:placeY,ph:0,h:0,g:0,f:0,c:0};
                    nodeLst.push(moveNode);                                             
                }
                tileCount ++;               
            }   
        }
        return nodeLst;
    }
```

My grid code. In case.

Thanks guys,

james-

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little? Is it that the tank shouldn't be able to reach the "isolated" tiles, because the water has an added movement cost, and you want to remove any unreachable tiles from the red diamond?

Comment: That's exactl it David.

Comment: I'm still digesting Vespers reply but it is like I need to know the cost, with the cost of going around the obstacles factored in, of each and every tile within the 4 tile movement limit of the tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a limited (distance-wise) breadth-first A* search right over that grid, with obstacles playing as walls in the algorithm. This will generate a set of reachable nodes each with distance_left attribute available, in a way that your "isolated tiles" will not get listed. Your code seems to just get the diamond pattern out of starting position and passage matrix, without actual check of the path distance.

```
public static function getReachableTiles(startTile:Point,distance:int):Array {
    var d:Dictionary=new Dictionary(); // will hold visited tiles point by point
    var o:Object={d:distance,px:startTile.x,py:startTile.y}; // a simple object info
    // add fields as necessary
    var a:Array=new Array(); // output array
    a.push(o);
    d[startTile.y*256+startTile.x]=o; // the simplest hash. You have to ensure 
    // these never overlap for different pairs of [x,y], and the same hash
    // function is used across this method
    while (distance>0) {
        for each (o in a) {
            if (o.d!=distance) continue; // already parsed
            var to:Object={d:distance-1,px:o.x-1,py:o.y};
            if (Game.isPassable(to.x,to.y)&&!d[to.y*256+to.x]) {
                // a new cell, and is valid for the tank to pass
                // "isPassable" returns true if (x,y) corresponds to a passable and 
                // valid position. For example, (-1,2) might return false as it's off borders
                d[to.y*256+to.x]=to; // add to dictionary - a parsed cell
                a.push(to); // and to output
            }
            // doing the same for 3 other possible moves
            to={d:distance-1,px:o.x,py:o.y-1};
            if (Game.isPassable(to.x,to.y)&&!d[to.y*256+to.x]) {
                d[to.y*256+to.x]=to;
                a.push(to);
            }
            to={d:distance-1,px:o.x+1,py:o.y};
            if (Game.isPassable(to.x,to.y)&&!d[to.y*256+to.x]) {
                d[to.y*256+to.x]=to;
                a.push(to);
            }
            to={d:distance-1,px:o.x,py:o.y+1};
            if (Game.isPassable(to.x,to.y)&&!d[to.y*256+to.x]) {
                d[to.y*256+to.x]=to;
                a.push(to);
            }
        } // okay, entire array was parsed for new cells
        distance--; // we've iterated A* once more, lessen the distance
    }
    // at this point, we've iterated A* "distance" times, return
    return a;
}
```

You need to adjust this snippet for your variable structure, so that `Game.isPassable()` will be a valid call, and there would be the actual grid under your drawn map. Note, `startTile` is a grid-based set of coordinates, not pixel-based. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the essential solution. Am I missing something about the `&&!d` conditional though? I was expecting `&&!d[to.y*256+to.x]` instead as a visited check.

Comment: @DavidMear Right, it was me doing bad copy-paste. Fixed.

Comment: @DavidMear I'm not sure this will work guys. I am a bit confused with what the to.y*256+to.x does. It looks to be only a lookup label in the dictionary for that particular object. Or does it have another use? In A* you have a start and a destination and can adjust the cost values for tiles in between those 2 points. I already know the cost from the start node to each node within the 4 tile limit and I've filtered out the tiles beyond that and given the tiles with obstacles property of true. What I don't know is the adjusted cost of each tile factoring in the obstacles. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have come back, humbled in your presence. How's that as an appolgy for not believing you! After I found out a hash was a quick way of looking something up and realized you were looking at only complete paths and not the numbers I saw how it would work. Live and learn. Thanks guys. I wish would have done this a month ago!